# Env переменные и API key React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, .env

У меня API_KEY записан в .env файл как REACT_APP_API_KEY. Насколько я знаю эти файлы не пушат в репозиторий, следовательно вопрос: Откуда реакт возьмёт этот ключ (например при сборке/деплое на vercel/heroku) ?

Comment: Вы там сами уже должны в сервисах указать эти переменные окружения.  Независимо от проекта.

Answer (score 0):

При создании проекта на vercel/heroku и тому подобное Вам предложат создать "Переменные среды"/"Environment Variables"